# How to pass database data as props in getServerSideProps in NextJS

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I want to pass the user data I fetched from a MongoDB database using the user id to the props in the return section. how can I send the data `docs` in the callback function to the `props` correctly?

Thanks for your response.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (userid) => {
  await connectMongo();
  console.log("db connected on profile page");

  User.findOne({ id: userid }, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(docs.email);
    }
  });
  return {
    props: {

    },
  };

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used MongoDB in the frontend as well, **I have added a snippet to give a full example**. However simply put you'll need to store the result of the DB find request in a variable and if you're just searching with a `findOne()` or looking for **one result** I suggest storing the result of the find in a variable and sending it directly to the page as a prop.

However you will need to call `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results))` if you have **multiple results** from a `db.collection("submissions").find()` request.

**Client Side /page/...**

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({req}) {
  let env = process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "-dev" : "";

  const client = await clientPromise;
  const db = client.db('FormSubmissions' + env);
  const forwarded = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];

  const ipAddress = typeof forwarded === 'string' ? forwarded.split(/, /)[0] : req.socket.remoteAddress;

  let _submissionsByIP = await db.collection("submissions").find({
    ipAddress: ipAddress,
  })

  let submissionsByIP = await _submissionsByIP.toArray();
  console.log('submissionsByIP',submissionsByIP);

  return {
    props: {
      submissionsByIP: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(submissionsByIP)),
    },
  };
}

function Support_Sales({submissionsByIP}) {
...
}
```

**clientPromise**

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const options = {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
}

let client
let clientPromise

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI" - Add Mongo URI to .env.local')
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise
} else {
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
  clientPromise = client.connect()
}

export default clientPromise
```

Comment: @Nsikan If you're passing a value to userid I don't see where. Without that it's hard to help more. I think after you explain your source of userid you'll get better help.

Comment: that userid is coming from another page as a query using   const userid = router.query.userid; with the useRouter(). when I store the result of the docs variable in another variable, I am unable to pass it as a props to the return statement. I declared the variable before the User.findOne, and assigned it inside the else block, but when trying to assign it in the props section it sends an empty variable back to the client.

Comment: thanks, I solved it like this: 

 let userData = await User.findOne({ _id: userid.params.id});
  return {
    props: {
      user: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userData)),
    },
  };

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new variable to solve the problem

```
let userData = {};
User.findOne({ id: userid }, function (err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(docs.email);
    userData = docs
  }
});

return {
  props: {
    user: userData
  }
};
```

there is another solution by using `async`. the code be like:

```
const userData = async User.findOne({ id: userid });

return {
  props: {
    user: userData
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but when I assigned docs to userdata it works inside that else block of code, but if I try to console.log that userdata outside, before the return statement, it has no values, hence nothing gets passed to the props in the return statement.

Comment: you are right, as you already found your solution, its a good step. but i do agree with @Apezdr 's answer to storing the variable. that's is the best approach